# Docker multi target build failed on Docker Hub

Tags: docker, dockerfile

For unknown reason build failed on Docker Hub when it trying to copy from a just built target into the same Dockerfile. When, I try on local machine (Fedora 27, Docker CE 17.12), the build succeed.

Here the failed build log : https://hub.docker.com/r/emmanuelgautier/react-app/builds/bsygsbahuzdxfbsqr5r9er4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder `/usr/src/app/build` doesn't exist in the second image because according to [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> `CMD` does not execute anything at build time, but specifies the
>   intended command for the image.

`RUN` should be used instead of `CMD` where `yarn build` command executes.

The correct `Dockerfile` is:

```
## Development environment target
FROM node as dev-env

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY [ "package*.json", "yarn.lock", "./" ]
RUN yarn install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT [ "./docker-entrypoint.sh" ]

## Build environment target
FROM node as build-env

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY [ "package*.json", "yarn.lock", "./" ]
RUN yarn install --production

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

## Production environement target
FROM nginx as production-env

LABEL MAINTAINER Emmanuel Gautier <docker@emmanuelgautier.fr>

COPY --from=1 /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 443 80
```

Comment: Success. Thanks for your help